# How would one model wage suppression from non-poaching agreements?

Tags: macroeconomics, wages

**Motivating example:** Google, Apple, Microsoft et al were recently fined $430 million for wage collusion and anti-trust violations regarding hiring of employees. Their employees were involved in a class action lawsuit. My uninformed guess is that the wage collusion and anti-poaching agreements adversely affected market wages as a whole for everyone in software. I'd like to know how one might prove that.

To limit the scope of the question a little: **how would one go about calculating the impact of anti-poaching agreements on market wages?** My intuition for a solution involves brute forcing an implausibly accurate dataset, but I know you economists are clever folks.